Talend ETL Job SQL with if condition
I have two database (MySQl and SQL Server), I use a query that return values from Mysql for example:



ID
STATUS




1
OK


2
ERRO


3
ERRO


4
OK


5
ERRO



I would like that after the (tJavaRow_1) to check if context.var_status_oc == "ERRO" then update SQL SERVER, but the job only check the last result(5).
tJavaRow_1 I use:
context.var_oc = input_row.ID; (String)
context.var_status_oc = "ERRO".equals(input_row.STATUS); (Boolean)
if condition
context.var_status_oc == true

I expect the result (2, 3, 5), maybe a for each update
Obs.: Sorry, English is my second language and I'm learning

For the tJavaRow_1 component, can you please clean up and format the code that it contains because as of right now, I don’t see how that would even compile.
